# Serialize Abstract class with different attribute name

Tags: c#, serialization

Working on an export flow, I have a few XML elements that represent the same thing, but with a different name. I can't change those names as they're defined by the other software.

I need something like that:

```
<class1>
  <MY_FIELD></MY_FIELD>
</class1>

<class2>
  <my_field></my_field>
</class2>
```

As the treatments that need to be done on both fields are the same, I wanted to create an abstract class that contains it.

Right now, this is what I have:

```
public abstract class MyAbstract
{
    [XmlAttribute("MY_FIELD")]
    public MyField {get;set;}
}

[Serializable]
public class Class1 : MyAbstract
{
}

[Serializable]
public class Class2 : MyAbstract
{
}
```

Is there a way to specify a different `XmlAttribute` on the final class (`class1` and `class2`) so I can set the attribute on `MyField` ?

**Edit**:
I'm trying to use `XmlAttributeOverrides`, that seems to do what I want, but I can't make it work. I don't know what I am missing.

```
var myType = typeof(Class1);
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
var attrs = new XmlAttributes
{
  XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("test")
};
overrides.Add(myType, "MyField",attrs);
```

and for the serializer

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(myType, overrides);
```

**Edit2**:
Finally I end up removing the attribute on my abstract class and add a getter on each class for serialization purpose. It's crappy but I still hope someone can give me a proper option.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public abstract class MyAbstract
{
    abstract public MyField {get;set;}
}

[Serializable]
public class Class1 : MyAbstract
{
    [XmlAttribute("MY_FIELD")]
    public override MyField {get;set;}
}

[Serializable]
public class Class2 : MyAbstract
{
    [XmlAttribute("my_field")]
    public override MyField {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: doesn't worked, got an serialization exception when doing it.

Comment: What did the exception say?

Comment: Nothing that deserve interest. Something like "InvalidOperationException. An error occurs during serialization", i didn't save it

Comment: You need to add `override` on the subclasses' properties.